# Some Docker containers don't run when created from the command line while they run when created from the Desktop app

Tags: docker

When I run `docker run <image>` from the command line, a container gets created (as seen in `docker ps -a`) but then it doesn't run (as seen in `docker ps`). `docker start <container>` doesn't fix that: the container just doesn't want to run.

However, when I initialize a container from the Desktop app on Mac OS (Monterey), that container then runs just fine both from the Desktop app and the terminal. The container appears in `docker ps`, I can stop it (`docker stop`) and then start it again (`docker start`). No problems.

So, it is about *how I initialize* containers from images (the `docker run` command). What gives? Maybe, I don's specify some required args when running the command in the terminal?

Here's the images I've identified to have such an issue:

- `ubuntu:latest`
- `ubuntu:18.04`
- `Python:3.7`
- `Python:3.9`
- `Python:3.9.9-bullseye`

While those images run fine (i.e. I can spin up containers from them using simple `docker run` in the terminal):

- `nextcloud:latest`
- `mongo:latest`

Answer (score 1):

A Docker container is a wrapper around a single *process*.  Docker runs the process, and when it runs the process, the container exits.  You don't usually "log into a container" and it's not usually important to "keep a container running".

If you look at your lists of containers, the second groups are actually running some server, so it makes sense to

```sh
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 mongo:latest
```

to launch a MongoDB instance.  The first group of containers is just bases for other things, though; if you have an unmodified `ubuntu` container, what do you expect its main process to be?  In its `Dockerfile` it happens to be an interactive shell, but that means if you run

```sh
docker run -d ubuntu:latest
```

the shell determines it doesn't have any input and exits, taking the container with it.

You won't usually have occasion to run unmodified base images like `ubuntu` or `python` directly.  Use these in the `FROM` line of your `Dockerfile`.

You won't usually need `docker start`.  If a container stops, you should generally get a new container from a clean known state by `docker rm` the existing container and `docker run` a new one.  Deleting and recreating containers like this is extremely routine (you need to do it to change core Docker options or whenever the application code changes) and you may need to do a little planning around it.

Comment: Thank you! But why does, say, a Mongo process continues running and keeping the container "alive" while the shell in, for example, the Ubuntu container just terminates?

Comment: The _process_ the MongoDB container runs is `mongod`.  What _process_ does a bare `ubuntu` container run?

Comment: So, a shell is not a process like `mongod`? Although, even if they are technically similar, it indeed wouldn't make sense to run such a bare container.

Comment: `mongod` just runs; it doesn't try to read its input.  A shell is in fact a process too, but once it reaches the end of its input it exits, and when it exits, the container exits too.

Comment: Right... standard input. Okay, thank you very much for the help! I'm gonna go continue my Docker journey